# ExtJs 5 - launch function not executed in Ext.application

Tags: javascript, django, extjs

I am new to extjs, and I try to integrate extjs 5 with django 1.7 on my localhost. I have set the backend and got the rest api work (at /api/), as at https://github.com/MaZderMind/django-vs-extjs , but when the index.html runs app.js, which displays the login page, it seems that:

- The controller file (Login.js) isn't loaded,
- the launch function is not executed.

In firebug I can see that it reads the function definition and then returns without executing it automatically (also, when defining controller it steps over like it is simple command, but on the require statement steps into the function that fetches them), hence the login page is not displayed. But the other js files (for authentication) are loaded, as I see in console. Do you have any ideas what is happening? The codes are:

- app.js

```js
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

Ext.application({
 
 // base-package of all classes
 name: 'MyApp',
 
 // url to load js-files from - adapted to django project
 appFolder : 'static/static',
 
 // required controllers
 controllers: ['Login'],
 
 // other required components
 requires: [
  'MyApp.helper.CrsfTokenHelper',
  'MyApp.helper.PhantomStoreInserter'
 ],
 
 // application launch method
 launch: function () {
  
  // save the scope
  var app = this;
  console.log('launched');

  // ensure the user is logged in before showing her the main navigation with all our application goodies
  app.getController('Login').ensureLoggedIn(function(userinfo) {
   
   console.log('Login-Controller ensured that user', userinfo.username, 'is is currently loggeg in. Proceeding to navigation.')
   // upate display of the navigation conteoller and show it
   //app.getController('Navigation')
   //.updateUserinfo(userinfo)
   //.view.show();
   console.log('Here should be loaded the view after the login page');
  });
 }
});
```

- Login.js (controller)

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Login', {
  
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
 mixins: ['Ext.mixin.Observable'],
 views: ['Login'],
 
 // pointers into the view
 refs: [
  { 'ref': 'userField', selector: '#user' },
  { 'ref': 'passField', selector: '#pass' },
  { 'ref': 'submitButton', selector: '#submit' }
 ],
 
 // stored user information as received from the server
 userinfo: null,
 
 // controller initialisation
 init: function() {
  
  // save the scope
  var loginController = this;
  
  // create an instance of the view
  var win = loginController.loginWindow = loginController.getView('Login').create();
  this.control({
   
   // register for the login-click
   '#submit': {
    click: function() {
     
     // retrieve username & password from view
     var username = this.getUserField().getValue(), password = this.getPassField().getValue();
      
     // mask the form out
     win.mask('Verifying…');
     
     // process the login with the backend
     loginController.performLogin(username, password, function(success) {
      
      // the user was successfully authorized
      if(success) {
       // now request additional information on the user (name and such)
       loginController.fetchLoginStatus(function(userinfo) {
        // test if the server responded with data as expected
        if(userinfo) {
         // hide the login-window
         win.hide();
         // store received information locally
         loginController.userinfo = userinfo;
         // raise a event on the controller when finished
         loginController.fireEvent('login', userinfo);
         loginController.fireEvent('ready', userinfo);
        }
        // we did not receive valid data from the server
        // this sould not fail, but if it does, just handle it like a failed login
        else {
         // disable the login on the form
         win.unmask();
         // set error-message on password-field
         loginController.clearPasswordAndFocus().setPasswordError('Invalid Username or Password!');
        }
       })
      }
      // authorization was not successful
      // unmask the form, show an error message and restart login process
      else {
      win.unmask();
      loginController.clearPasswordAndFocus().showError('Invalid Username or Password!');
      }
     })
    }
   }
  });
  
  // register keyboard handler
  this.nav = new Ext.KeyNav(win.getEl(), {
   
   // enter key -> login-button click
   enter: function() {
    loginController.getSubmitButton().fireEvent('click')
   }
  });
 },
 
 // test if the user is logged in.
 // if she is, call back immediatly. if she is not, show a login form
 // delay the callback until she logged in successfully
 ensureLoggedIn: function(callback) {
 
  // save the scope
  var loginController = this;
  
  // test if the backend knows us
  loginController.fetchLoginStatus(function(userinfo) {
  
   // analyze if a user is logged in
   if(userinfo) {
    // callback, if she is
    loginController.userinfo = userinfo;
    loginController.fireEvent('ready', userinfo);
    return callback(userinfo);
   }
   // no, we're not. show the login-window
   console.log('no user logged in, showing login-window');
   // login-testing and re-trying is handled by the handler set in the init-method
   // it raises an event on the controller once it is finished
   // we listen on this event and relay it to our callback - but only once
   // -> the callback shouldn't be called multiple times
   loginController.on('login', callback, {single: true});
   // initiate login procedure by showing the login window
   loginController.loginWindow.show();
   loginController.clearForm();
  });
 },
 
 // ask the backend if and which user is currently logged in
 fetchLoginStatus: function(callback) {
  
  console.info('requesting current userinfo from backend');
  Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '/api/auth/user/',
   success: function(response) {
    
    // decode json-response
    var userinfo = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    
    // request user permission list
    Ext.Ajax.request({
     
     url: '/api/auth/permissions/',
     success: function(response) {
      // decode json-response
      userinfo.permissions = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
      // callback with the decoded response
      console.log('received userinfo:', userinfo);
      callback(userinfo);
     },
     failure: function(response) {
      // callback without info
      console.log('received no permission list - nobody logged in');
      callback();
     }
    });
   },
   failure: function(response) {
    // callback without info
    console.log('received no userinfo - nobody logged in');
    callback();
   }
  });
 },
 
 // submit username & password to the backend
 performLogin: function(username, password, callback) {
  
  console.info('trying to log into backend with username=', username, 'password=', password.length, 'Chars');
  
  // send login data via ajax to the server and callback with result
  Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '/api/auth/login/',
   method: 'POST',
   params: {
    'username': username,
    'password': password
   },
   success: function(){
    callback(true);
   },
   failure: function() {
    callback(false);
   }
  });
 },
 
 // ask the backend to throw away our session which makes us logged out
 performLogout: function(callback) {
  
  console.info('trying to log out from backend');
  
  // ensure userinfo is unset
  this.userinfo = null;
  Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '/api/auth/logout/',
   method: 'GET',
   success: function(){
    callback(true);
   },
   failure: function() {
    callback(false);
   }
  });
 },
 
 // shorthand to test iff userinfo is available
 isLoggedIn: function() {
  // null -> false, string -> true
  return !!this.userinfo;
 },
 
 // shorthand to get the current username
 getUserinfo: function() {
  return this.userinfo;
 },
 
 // shorthand to get the current username
 getUsername: function() {
  return this.isLoggedIn() ? this.getUserinfo().username : null;
 },
 
 // shorthand to get the current username
 getPermissions: function() {
  return this.isLoggedIn() ? this.userinfo.permissions.user_permissions : [];
 },
 
 // shorthand to get the current username
 isSuperuser: function() {
  return this.isLoggedIn() ? this.userinfo.permissions.is_superuser : [];
 },
 
 hasPermission: function(permission) {
  return this.isLoggedIn() && (this.isSuperuser() || this.getPermissions().indexOf(permission) !== -1)
 },
 
 // clears all form elements in the view
 clearForm: function() {
  this.loginWindow.unmask();
  this.getPassField().setValue('').unsetActiveError();
  this.getUserField().setValue('').unsetActiveError();
  this.getUserField().focus();
  return this;
 },
 
 // clears the password-field in the view and sets the typing-focus to it
 clearPasswordAndFocus: function() {
  this.getPassField().setValue('').focus();
  return this;
 },
 
 // set an error-message on the password-fieldy
 setPasswordError: function(msg) {
  this.getPassField().setActiveErrors([msg]);
  return this;
 }
});
```

- Login.js (view)

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login', {
 
 extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
 renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
 id: "loginBox",
 title: 'Login',
 width: 400,
 layout: 'form',
 bodyPadding: 5,
 closable: false,
 resizable: false,
 draggable: false,
 defaultFocus: 'user',
 defaultType: 'textfield',
 
 items: [{
   itemId: 'user',
   fieldLabel: 'Username',
   allowBlank: false
  },{
   inputType: 'password',
   fieldLabel: 'Password',
   itemId: 'pass',
   allowBlank: false
 }],
 
 buttons: [{
  text: 'Login',
  itemId: 'submit'
 }]
});
```

- console output:

GET *localhost* /static/static/helper/CrsfTokenHelper.js?_dc=1414444486439 200 OK 3ms   ext-all-debug.js (line 1010)

GET *localhost* /static/static/helper/PhantomStoreInserter.js?_dc=1414444486439 200 OK 2ms ext-all-debug.js (line 1010)

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently you are getting errors with your required files. If you comment the `requires` line inside your `Ext.application`:

```
Ext.application({

    // base-package of all classes
    name: 'MyApp',

    // url to load js-files from - adapted to django project
    appFolder : 'static/static',

    // required controllers
    controllers: ['Login'],

    // other required components
    //requires: [
    //  'MyApp.helper.CrsfTokenHelper',
    //  'MyApp.helper.PhantomStoreInserter'
    //],
    ...
});
```

You will see that your Login window will show up. Assuming of course that you have your folder structure setup correctly

```
index.html
app.js
static/
static/static/
static/static/controller/Login.js
static/static/view/Login.js
```

Comment: Indeed the problem was there. When I first created these helper files, I put the code there by just copying it from the source. But one of these files was empty (suppose wasn't saved?). My obsession to believe the error was because of the controller make me miss that. Feel very noob. Thanks for the great help on that Guilherme. Is so much appreciated. Cheers!!!